# jQuery not working when adding ease property

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, web, easing

I'm currently working on jQuery for animations in my website but the easing property is not working.

Here's the code:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $('div').animate({'height': '10px'}, 2000, 'easeInOutQuad');
}
);
```

Unfortunaltly, for some reason, it seems that jQuery doesn't recognize the `ease` property of `.animate()`, showing me a lot of errors, but only when I put ease property! Do I need to install something special? I only refers to jQuery 1.11.2.

Please help.

Comment: The [easings](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing) jQuery supports itself `[...] are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear[...]`. For `easeInOutQuad` you need jQuery-UI or another plugin that provides that easing.

Comment: Oh, ok! But the swing value act pretty exactly like the linear one...

Comment: So, I finally downloaded a jQuery plugin and everything works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear.

[jQuery animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

The easing you want to use is simply not implemented in the jQuery library. Additional easing options can be added with plugins (for example [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/easing/))

Comment: So, I finally downloaded a jQuery plugin and everything works perfectly! Thanks!